# Call method using type variable generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a scenario that i want to create one support class called D which contains a generic method. I have set the upper bound for type variable.

```
class A{
    void show(){
        System.out.println("Hello A");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    void msg(){
        System.out.println("Hello B");
    }
}

class C extends A{
    void msg(){
        System.out.println("Hello C");
    }
}

class D{
    <T extends A> void display(T ob){
        ob.msg(); //here i want to do some tricks
    }
}
```

First i want to share my objective. Here msg() function of B and C class has different implementations. I want to create one support class called D that has one display method, using display method i want to call either  msg() function of B or C class dependent on instantiation. Can you tell me how can i achieve it?

Comment: Just FYI, these are methods, not functions.

Comment: Can;t you check to see if **ob instanceof B** || **ob instanceof C**? Or maybe thats not what you are asking??

Comment: class `A` don't have a `msg` method, it is only declare in the subclass. So if `A` can be abstract, add an abstract method, if not, add an empty method (not good in the first place...). Or rename `show` in `A` to match the methods name in `B` and `C` (if they should be the same)

Comment: One of options: introduce an `interface M{void msg();}` which will be implemeted by `B` and `C`, so no generics required.

Comment: @kan but using `T extends A`, `T` will only "see" the methods of `A`, if the interface is only implemented in `B` and `C`, this won't work. It need to be implemented in `A`.

Comment: @AxelH I thought about that. i have declared one empty msg() method. But is it good coding pattern??

Comment: @AxelH Yeah, sure. In this case `display` should take `M` of course.

Comment: If you have/would have `class E extends A` without `msg()` - what `display` should do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the method `msg()` in class `A`, otherwise the `display()` method in class `D` does not know if this method exist or not in the object that you're passing to it. (What if someone makes a class `E` that extends `A` but does not have a `msg()` method, and you pass an `E` to `D.display()`?).

If you don't want to implement the `msg()` method in class `A`, then you can make it `abstract` (and you'll also have to make the class `abstract`).

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract void msg();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

more like an architecture style, I would use an interface for that, so your generic method constrains to `<T extends If> void display(T ob)` where If is the interface with the abstract method `msg`

```
interface If {
    void msg();
}

class A {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("Hello A");
    }
}

class B extends A implements If {
    @Override
    public void msg() {
        System.out.println("Hello B");
    }
}

class C extends A implements If {
    @Override
    public void msg() {
        System.out.println("Hello C");
    }
}

class D {
    <T extends If> void display(T ob) {
        ob.msg(); // here i want to do some tricks
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it changing the method definition ? You can't pass an `A` instance anymore. But indeed, this is a clean solution

Comment: OP doesnt need an A object, OP needs something that can implement the msg method

Comment: What I mean is you can't use it like `A a = new B(); new D().display(a);`.What the original definition was accepting. And of course, you lose the possibilities to use `A.show()`. Not a problem here, but this need to be point out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need generics for this, there is basic concept called dynamic binding in Java.

```
abstract class A{
    void show(){
        System.out.println("Hello A");
    }       
     abstract void msg();    
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
    void msg(){
        System.out.println("Hello B");
    }
}

class C extends A{

       @Override
       void msg(){
             System.out.println("Hello C");
       }
}

class D{
    void display(A ob){
        ob.msg(); 
    }
}
```

Here an appropriate instance provided to method will determine which class    method should in called at runtime.